# How to prevent character model from leaning in front of inventory

Tags: borderlands-2

Much of my inventory management time focuses on setting items to trash [x] or favorite [star] while comparing with currently equipped items.

Unfortunately, between the slow sway of the character and the slow sway of the inventory screen itself, while in comparison mode the right side of the inventory is often hidden by the character model. Axton is especially rude:

[image: Axton thrusting his chest in front of my inventory]

If I try to click the [x] or [star] blind, I often click the wrong one or accidentally equip an item I'm just trying to tag. Non-solutions:

- I can click-drag up/down to temporarily pull the character out of the way,
  but once I let go it bounces back to its original location.
- I can click-drag left/right to rotate the character model, but most rotations are even worse than the default.

Occasionally, though, the character model blessedly disappears completely:

[image: Yay! No Axton!]

Often it's this way if I go to inventory immediately upon starting. And sometimes this happens when I rotate the character model, but it's inconsistent. Just now I tried it with Salvador (didn't work) and Axton (worked about half the time).

Is there a way to make the character model disappear consistently?

Comment: Oh man, that sucks.

Comment: Have you tried rotating with the right stick while in the inventory? I think it's right anyways. Edit: NVM didn't see that you already tried it before posting

Comment: Axton is rude? Did you play Krieg? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this discussion in the Steam community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/846938350856537787/):

> Stand next to a wall, the "camera" will move to prevent the screen from being obstructed and subsequently will be too out of position for your character to be in the line of sight.

And if your character still doesn't behave:

> Well, I ran straight up to a wall and opened my inventory and was immediately disappointed to see my character's image on the screen. Then I held MLB and twisted the screen and *POP*, it disappeared!

---

Another point that may be of interest, following [another discussion in the Steam community](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/864969481877422998/):

> It might be your resolution, i run at 2560x1440 and he sits at the side nicely like all the other chars.

Comment: Kludgy but effective. It's a little touchy -- turns out you can't put stand against just any solid thing. Still, this will make inventory management more pleasant. Thanks.